# How to use git bundle?

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out how to use git bundle.  I have followed the instructions I have found on various web pages, but to no avail.

I have created a bundle, myrepo.bundle on one machine.  I move it to another machine.  I verify it, and it seems OK:

```
>$ git bundle verify myrepo.bundle                                                                                                                              
The bundle contains this ref:                                                                                                                                         
d318d27fff313dc12f28a2b405c8035028c829b1 HEAD                                                                                                                         
The bundle requires this ref:                                                                                                                                         
d7789429bd6daae1c85da0d6419892137a743142                                                                                                                              
myrepo.bundle is okay
```

Then I try to do a fetch, and all I get is an error I don't understand:

```
>$ git fetch ./myrepo.bundle master:central-master                                                                                                              
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
```

That required ref is definitely in the destination repo, BTW.  And the bundle was created from the master branch of the source repo.  Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry.  That doc page doesn't help.  I can't see a solution anywhere.  Thanks just the same.

Comment: What if you omit `master:central-master`?

Comment: Actually, ":central-master" (i.e. leave out "master") gave me a new branch called "central-master".  I can work with that, merge it back into "master".  Maybe that's clumsy, but it works!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be that the bundle contains only the ref name `HEAD`, which is not a *branch* name. The `:central-master` trick made Git use `HEAD` as the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bundle doesn't have anything but the `HEAD` ref. You get bundles like that when you make an incremental bundle from e.g. a tag checkout.

```
git fetch ./myrepo.bundle HEAD:refs/heads/central-master
```

if you're sure the bundled commit is what you think it is.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!